# Trying to display a title in my python graph

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, arduino-uno

I'm making an oscilloscope with python and Arduino UNO. And I'm having two strange problems. First, I would like to emphasize that my code works, but I want to understand why these problems happen.

Firstly, if I try to title my figure, my code stops working. I've commented and ended with 3 question marks `???` the three lines concerned.

See code:
My second question is why the buttons are not colorful (they are all black) and not clickable. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q0R0.png)

```
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *


voltsent = [] #le signal reçu en chaine de caractères
signalsentfloat = [] #le signal reçu converti en float
ser = serial.Serial("com9",115200)
#affichage interactive des données
plt.ion()
cnt = 0

def figuresignal(): #fonction qui affiche le siganl analogue
    #fig = plt.figure()                                          ???
    plt.grid(True)
    #plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    #fig.suptitle('Visualisation de signaux générés par le GBF')  ???
    plt.ylabel('Signal')
    plt.plot(voltsent, '.')
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.ylabel('Fourrier Transform')
    plt.plot(voltsentFT, '-')


 while True: #while loop that loops forever
     while(ser.inWaiting()==0) :#wait here until there is a data
         pass
     signalsent = ser.readline() #read line of text from serial port
     signalsentfloat = float(signalsent) #convert it
     voltsent.append(signalsentfloat) #append its values to array
     voltsentFT = np.fft.fft(voltsent)
     drawnow(figuresignal) #call drawnow to update our the graph
     #plt.pause(.000001)
     cnt = cnt+1
     if(cnt>50):
         voltsent.pop(0)
```

Comment: What do you mean colorful? Are they not black all the time? You can set the title using `plt.title('My Graphs')`

Comment: You know, these icons at the bottom left of my figure. I've seen some plottings on th inernet, they 'icons) are in color.

Answer (score 1):

`fig = plt.figure()` creates a new figure. So you would end up with *a lot* of figures, eventually leading the application to crash. What you want instead is to have one single figure, so put `fig = plt.figure()` outside the loop.

Since this would still plot a lot of lines on top of each other, the better option is to update the lines.

```
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

voltsent = [] #le signal reçu en chaine de caractères
signalsentfloat = [] #le signal reçu converti en float
ser = serial.Serial("com9",115200)
#affichage interactive des données
plt.ion()
cnt = 0

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle(u'Visualisation de signaux générés par le GBF')

ax = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel('Signal')
line1, = ax.plot([],".")

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_ylabel('Fourrier Transform')
line2, = ax2.plot([],"-")

def figuresignal(): #fonction qui affiche le siganl analogue
    line1.set_data(np.arange(len(voltsent)),voltsent )    
    line2.set_data(np.arange(len(voltsentFT)),voltsentFT )

while True: #while loop that loops forever
    while(ser.inWaiting()==0) :#wait here until there is a data
        pass
    signalsent = ser.readline() #read line of text from serial port
    signalsentfloat = float(signalsent) #convert it
    voltsent.append(signalsentfloat) #append its values to array
    voltsentFT = np.fft.fft(voltsent)
    figuresignal()
    plt.pause(.001)
    cnt = cnt+1
    if(cnt>50):
        voltsent.pop(0)
```

Comment: I tried what you said but still not working. I am pretty sure that the problem resides in the of """suptitle""""" , but I don't know why.
If I comment that line out, problem disappears.

Comment: Can you please be more precise what exactly is not working?

Comment: The graphs do not appear in the figure window when I remove the comment symbol in the """""suptitle line"""""
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are you talking about the code in this answer? It would not matter if you put a suptitle or not in the plot.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about the post above. 
I know it doesn't matter, but I wanted to understand why.
Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Do you get an error about the unicode symbols? Use `u"..."`.

Comment: No, just the figure window with no graph

Comment: It might depend on the environment in use, whether `ion` is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem in above question by following a tutorial on [Toptechboy.com](http://%60http://www.toptechboy.com/tutorial/python-with-arduino-lesson-8-introduction-to-graphing-with-matplotlib/)
To give a title to my graph I used the function :  plt.title('Le titre ici')